# Python Inheritance: what is the difference?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

Given a parent class 'A'

```
Class A(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

What is the difference between making a subclass 'B' among the below options

Option 1

```
Class B(A):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

Option 2

```
Class B(A):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        A.__init__(self, a, b)
        self.c = c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, none. But what if `A.__init__` did loads of complex logic? You don't want to have to duplicate all that in B.

An enhancement on Option 2 is to use the `super()` function:

```
class B(A):
    def __init_(self,a,b,c):
        super(B, self).__init__(a, b)
        self.c = c
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `super(B, self)` instead of `super(A, self)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your first option initializes members of class `A` (`a` and `b`) as if it was in class `B`.

The second option uses constructor of `A` to initialize members of `A` before initializing members of `B`.

A better approach to design classes in Python would be

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @property
    def b(self):
       return self._b

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super(B, self).__init__(a, b)
        self._c = c

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c
```

The `_` in member names mentions that the members should not be accessed directly. The decorator `@property` provides direct accessors for the members.

Note that members are read only. This class have no setters specified. For example, setter for `c` can be declared as follows

```
@c.setter
def c(self, c):
    self._c = c
```